# How to make yield work with this.req.on('data') without requiring more modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, yield, co

Obviously, the reason here is because of the async nature of `on('data')`, and the combination of using yield, but how can I make this work? I tried "thunkifying" `_this.req.on`, but to no avail. I'm still getting the hang of generators, yield and thunks but I'm a bit stumped here.

Is there any other clever solution **without requiring another module dependency**?

```
var thunkify = require('thunkify');
var request = thunkify(require('request'));

//...

if (['GET', 'DELETE'].indexOf(_this.req.method) === -1) {
        _this.req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            options.json = chunk.toString();
        });
    }

//...

var resp = yield request(options);
_this.body = resp[0].body;
```

Comment: Can you please show your whole code? I think I can answer your question, but I'm not sure what you are doing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by using `co-body` module. Here's an example:

```
var thunkify = require('thunkify');
var request = thunkify(require('request'));
var parse = require('co-body');

//...

if (['GET', 'DELETE'].indexOf(_this.req.method) === -1) {
        options.json = yield parse.json(_this.req);
    }

//...

var resp = yield request(options);
_this.body = resp[0].body;
```

BUT, I don't like the fact that I have to require another module every time I have to do something. Anyone got a better one?

Comment: Is this another question or an answer?

Comment: i figured i do a bit more digging on my own since no one has replied yet.. though I don't like my answer, so I'm waiting if anyone has a better one.

Comment: this is the way you should be doing it.